# How does fetch api work in javascript? I am getting undefiend while trying to fetch data even though the data is there

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am testing this on playcode.io so it should work for everyone.
In this code

```
let stockPriceData= new Map();
const generateMapofStockPriceData = async () =>{
    await fetch('https://64607244fe8d6fb29e30eaaf.mockapi.io/Xerodha/V1/StockPriceData')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data.forEach(element =>{
      console.log(element.StockPrice);
      stockPriceData.set(element.StockName,element.StockPrice);
    }))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));    
    }
    generateMapofStockPriceData();
    console.log(stockPriceData);
    console.log(stockPriceData.get("ASIANPAINT"));
```

The first console.log prints the map which makes me believe that the map was already generated but then the next line gives undefined and after the the elements print the stock price which means that the first console log was actually having no data i.e. the stockPriceData map has no data but something like the promise got resolved and I got the data much later. How does this actually work and how do I get the values given the key ?

Note: I put the async await much later without having much idea but it works the same without it.

Answer (score 0):

generateMapofStockPriceData is an asyncronous fn. so all the code below invoking of this func will be executed before finishing it so you have two option

1. move all code to above fn
2. pass a callback fn

   ```
   let stockPriceData = new Map();        
   const generateMapofStockPriceData = async (callbackFn) => {

        const res = await fetch('https://64607244fe8d6fb29e30eaaf.mockapi.io/Xerodha/V1/StockPriceData')
        const data = await res.json()
        data.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.StockPrice);
            stockPriceData.set(element.StockName, element.StockPrice);
        })

        console.log(stockPriceData);
        console.log(stockPriceData.get("ASIANPAINT")); // or you can use call back 

        if (callbackFn) callbackFn()

    }

    generateMapofStockPriceData(); // this will take time code after this will be executed before finishing this . so pass a callback fn to execute after finishing above fn or move required code to above fn
   ```